# Look i downloaded a project from git hub and opened it in android studio but it is giving this,

Tags: flutter, android-studio, github

Resolving dependencies...
Because mi_card depends on cupertino_icons ^0.1.6 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

- Try upgrading your constraint on cupertino_icons: flutter pub add cupertino_icons:^1.0.6
  Process finished with exit code 1

i tried to do pub get and pub upgrade,
but it is giving this
i have even upgraded cupertino_icons from cupertino_icons:^1.0.4 to cupertino_icons:^1.0.6,
but still it is giving me the above error

Comment: Show us your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.